# Get Source URI of Image from code behind

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have an `Image` declared and `Source` specified in XAML with this code -

```
<Image x:Name="imgSomeFile" Source="Assets/someFile.png"/>
```

Is there a way I can access this source URI in the code-behind using only the name of the instance ? I've tried `image.Source` but that only gives the `BitmapImage` that the image uses and not the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UriSource` property of the `BitmapImage` you get from the source.

```
((imgSomeFile).Source as BitmapImage).UriSource.OriginalString
```